# snmp responder installing error : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysnmp>=5.0.0 (from snmpresponder)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysnmp

I am trying to install snmpresponder using the pip (in windows). I am using python 2.7. I found the snmpresponder from the following website. http://snmplabs.com/snmpresponder/

This is what I tried

```
pip install snmpresponder
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Collecting snmpresponder
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/47/5fee2bffe4b63f750d9f55118fce1796610eb2bf90b8526f584b05d56cb8/snmpresponder-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysnmp>=5.0.0 (from snmpresponder) (from versions: 4.1.16d, 4.1.12a0, 4.1.13a0, 4.1.15a0, 4.1.16a0, 4.1.16b0, 4.1.16rc0, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 4.2.5, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.3.2, 4.3.3, 4.3.4, 4.3.5, 4.3.6, 4.3.7, 4.3.8, 4.3.9, 4.3.10, 4.4.1, 4.4.2, 4.4.3, 4.4.4, 4.4.5, 4.4.6, 4.4.7, 4.4.8, 4.4.9, 4.4.10, 4.4.11, 4.4.12)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pysnmp>=5.0.0 (from snmpresponder)
```

and I checked my version it is showing 4.4.12 (using pip show pysnmp)

```
Name: pysnmp
Version: 4.4.12
Summary: SNMP library for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp
Author: Ilya Etingof
Author-email: etingof@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requires: pycryptodomex, pysmi, pyasn1
```

I also tried for the update also, still, it is showing version less than 5.0.0? So what should I do for installing the snmpresponder? Should I change pysnmp or download it using some other way. Please ask If you need more details. My basic need is to fix some error I am facing in the SNMP agent side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNMP responder tool is still in a work-in-progress state. Better pull `snmpresponder` from GitHub, it depends on GitHub version of pysnmp so the dependencies would be satisfied right away.

Comment: after installing from Git this is what I got.  ``` Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\snmpresponder-0.0.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for snmpresponder==0.0.3
Searching for pysnmp>=5.0.0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pysnmp/
No local packages or working download links found for pysnmp>=5.0.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pysnmp>=5.0.0')```

Comment: Well, you can always install pysnmp from Github master manually, if your pip version does not respect that git URL.